# A question regarding an orthonormal system in $L^2(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, lp-spaces

My instructor briefly discussed a result in lecture that I need help with. Here was the set up.

We assumed that $ \{ f_n \}$ is an orthonormal system in $L^2(0,1)$ and we supposed that there exists an $M > 0$ such that $|f_n(x)| \leq M$ a.e for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Furthermore, we let $ \{ c_n \}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_n f_n$ converges a.e.

They said that it was "clear" that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = 0.$$

This is not clear or intuitive for me.

---

After reading through the page, I am still a bit confused. Can someone put together a working proof to clear things up?

Comment: Do you know the basic result in infinite series that if $\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\;$ converges then $\;\lim a_n=0\;$ ? Well, there you go...together with the supposition you wrote. What your lecturer gave you seems to be in preparation for the trigonometric orthonormal basis, perhaps for Fourier series or stuff...

Comment: That is where we are headed. I was not familiar with that result sorry. Do you think you could tease out an explanation for me in regards to the problem. That would help my understanding out alot.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the sum of an infinite series is $\;S\;$ ,and we denote by $\;S_n\;$ the $\;n\,-$th element of the sequence of partial sums of the series. By *definition*, the series converges iff the limit of $\;S_n\;$ exists finitely ( and in this case $\;S_n\to S\;$) , so:

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\;,\;\;S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\implies a_n=S_n-S_{n-1}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\stackrel{\text{(arith. of limits)}}S-S=0$$

and we have the basic necessary condition for convergence of infinite series.

In your case you have $\;|c_nf_n|\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;$ (no matter whether real of complex numbers), but $\;\{f_n\}\;$ is a bounded sequence...! Finish the argument.

Comment: To finish the argument would I have that since $\{f_n \}$ is a bounded sequence,  we have that $\lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum_{n \to \infty} c_n f_n = 0$, which implies $ \sum_{n \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty}  c_n f_n = 0$ But since $\{f_n \}$ is an orthonormal set, $f_n \neq 0$ for each $n$. So $\lim_{n \to \infty}  c_n = 0.$ Is this correct?

Comment: @Emmak Exactly so...assuming that you already know that if the product of two sequences converges to zero and one of the sequences is bounded away from zero (which is what you actually need, not merely $\;f_n\neq0\;$ ...you in fact need to use that $\;||f_n||=1\;$ ...!), then the other one **must** converge to zero by itself. But this should be basic stuff at this point of your studies. Very nice !

Comment: Hmmm now I am a bit confused about having to use the fact that the norm of each $f_n = 1$. Could you elaborate on this part alittle more.

Comment: Take for example $\;c_n=n\;,\;\;f_n=\frac1{n^2}\;$ . Then $\;c_nf_n=\frac1n\to0\;$ , yet $\;\lim n\;$ isn't zero. We need boundness away from zero, meaning: $\;r<|f_n|\le M\;$ , for some *constant* $\;r>0\;$ . and then we can even use that convergent to zero times a bounded one converges to zero: $$|c_n|=|c_nf_n|\frac1{|f_n|}\to 0$$since $\;|c_nf_n|\to 0\;$ and $\;\frac1M<\frac1{|f_n}<\frac1r\;$ (bounded!)

Comment: I am not convinced that the answer is correct as it does not make use of orthonormality of the system $f_n.$ If we drop orthonormality assumption then we can take $f_n\equiv n^{-3}$ and $c_n=n.$ The series is clearly convergent.

Comment: The condition of orthonormality is completely meaningless for this.

Comment: @DonAntonio Can you please show me a proof of this that would not use the orthogonality

Comment: @EmmaK Exactly what I wrote in my answer and, perhaps, some of my comments above. There is nothing else to it: the sequence of a converging series must converge to zero. If you get this you already have 80% of the proof.

Comment: @DonAntonio its the other 20 percent that is messing with me

Comment: I really would like to know what *exactly* isn't clear to you. In a nutshell: if $\;\sum a_n\;$ converges then $\;\lim a_n=0\;$ This is basic series stuff. Thus, we get that $\;\lim c_nf_n=0\;$ . But $\;\{f_n\}\;$ is a set of non-zero **BOUNDED** elements (it doesn't really matter that they're an orthornomal system!), thus they are "bounded away from zero", as I wrote you in a comment above...Continue reading THERE.